# Derivative of a logarithm from Spivak's Calculus

Tags: calculus

Consider the function

$f(x) = 10^{x}$

and the inverse function

$f^{-1} = log_{10}$

In the book, Spivak defines the derivative as (page 337),

$\log^{'}_{10}(x) = \frac{1}{f^{'}(f^{-1}(x))}$

Why is this so?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that $f^{-1}$ and $f$ have the following relation $$f(f^{-1}(x)) = x$$ and differentiating the above we get $$f'(f^{-1}(x))(f^{-1})'(x) = 1$$ or $$(f^{-1})'(x) = \frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(x))}$$ This is what Spivak has written.

Comment: Interestingly, it's less work to start with $f\circ f^{-1}$.

Comment: @ThadJanisse: Yes I have made an edit to that effect.

Comment: Shouldn't $f'^{-1}(x)$ be $(f^{-1})'(x)$?

Comment: @MarkDickinson: I meant it to be like that but perhaps did not use the parenthesized notation. Will update the answer with your notation.